# python3 getting error TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

Tags: python

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from math import cos

# Setting the x - coordinates, 't' here // 
x = np.arange(0,10, 0.001)

# Setting the y - coordinates, 'f(t)' here//
y = 3*np.exp(-3*x)*cos(2*np.pi*x/3) - 5*x*np.exp(-x) - 2*np.exp(-x)

# Plotting f(t) vs t
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()

# Obtaining t values for g(t) //
x1 = np.arange(0, 4, 0.001)
x2 = np.arange(4, 10, 0.001)

# Plotting g(t)
plt.plot(x1, y)
plt.plot(x2, -y)
plt.show()

# Plotting median filtered function and original function

plt.plot(x, np.median(y))
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

so I'm trying to plot a function using python commands i have imported everything correctly but I'm getting the error TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars ad I'm stuck here don't know what to do next can anyone here help me get through it?

---

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/someplace/tmp.py", line 35, in <module>
    y = 3*np.exp(-3*x)*cos(2*np.pi*x/3) - 5*x*np.exp(-x) - 2*np.exp(-x)
TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

Comment: i have already read this answer and still I'm unable to debug my code!

Comment: What part don't you understand?  The post has `The error "only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars" is raised when the function expects a single value but you pass an array instead.` which is pretty clear IMO.  And when you run your code the error happens on the line `y = 3*np.exp(-3*x)*cos(2*np.pi*x/3) - 5*x*np.exp(-x) - 2*np.exp(-x)`.  So you're passing in an array to a function that expects a scalar

Comment: how do i change it to accept this function?

Comment: `math.cos` does not work with numpy arrays. Use `np.cos`.

Comment: Thank you it worked :)

Comment: When posting a question about code that produces an Exception, always include the complete Traceback - copy and paste it then format it as code (select it and type `ctrl-k`)